# Generate a hyperlink for each id

Tags: javascript, php, html, anchor

I have an HTML page with tens of elements with an id attribute. I want to have an on page navigation in the sidebar.
How can I get a bookmark link for each id ? like for each `id="N"` I need `<a href="#N">M</a>`
but not next to it, all in one separate place.

Edit: Even better (assuming I only have inline type of elements, headings in my case):
for each `<x id="N">M</x>` I need `<a href="#N">M</a>`

Edit2: Maybe you have a PHP or JS snippet or a Coda clip ? or a standalone tool. *I cannot run Python, Perl, CGI etc*

```
<h4 id="Units">Units</h4>
<h5 id="Direct Fire Units">Direct Fire Units</h5>
These units carry light, bullet based weapons and automatically fire at enemy units in their FoF. They do not harm friendly Units.
Shotgun Machine GunSniper Rifle
```

P.S. I'll do the `<ul>` and `<li>` myself

Comment: You want this done in php? Or client side? Please edit your tags to clarify. And what've you *tried* already, and what went wrong with that?

Comment: I'm serious when I ask: Is this even ***possible*** in php? I'd have thought JS, where it would be a snap. Interested to see the answers to this question. -- Ned Ludd

Comment: When you edit the original question, Please annotate the change(s) with **EDIT** or similar.

Comment: @David Thomas PHP or JS, doesn't matter it's not for visitors, I just need the output so I can have my sidebar done and hardcoded. I haven't tried anything because I suspect it would take me as long as doing it by hand.

Comment: Pete, that's why I asked about his implementation details, I imagine it *could* be done with PHP, but I'd hate to be the one tasked with doing so. Whereas in JavaScript it's pretty easy. The problem is there's no clarity in the 'how.' @user2534: could you post some sample mark-up that you're working with?

Comment: @David Thomas -- right, we commented at almost the same time. BUT this is a real interesting idea, it seems to me. Not in php, though.

Answer (score 1):

In plain JavaScript (and this took longer than I care to admit...sigh):

```
var navList = document.createElement('ol');
var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('h2');

document.body.insertBefore(navList,headers[0]);

for (i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
    newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newA = document.createElement('a');
    newA.href = '#' + headers[i].id;
    newA.innerHTML = headers[i].innerHTML;
    newLi.appendChild(newA);
    navList.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eFavL/).

Comment: Thx for your time, see my comment to Emil's answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about [something similar](http://jsfiddle.net/xS4MY/3/).

Since your question is not very clear, i would suggest that you edit the example i made and show us what you are looking for.

Comment: Thx, like I said it's not for visitors but for me. I needed the source so I [modified your code](http://jsfiddle.net/elddifsj/xS4MY/4/) so that I could copy the HTML output

Comment: …and also removed the list thing because it's likely to be nested wrong if there's nesting